# Cannot connect to my remote IP address without a reboot, multiple pieces of software affected

Tags: macos, network, ssh, vpn, domain

I just recently switched back to Mac OS after using a Windows 10 machine for a year. I have noticed an issue that existed with my previous Macbook Pro, and is now plaguing my new machine.

I have a private server sitting on my residential public/remote IP Address. When I take my new Macbook out of sleep and try to ssh into it, I will occasionally get this error:

`ssh: connect to host *myserver*: Can't assign requested address`

This is the exact error that I used to receive on my old Macbook Pro. Only a restart or an ifdown / ifup of my network interface resolves the problem.

This isn't just an error with ssh, either. I cannot connect my VPN to this server, or even visit the website that is hosted on it. Trying to access my domain / direct IP address in the browser (or via any other method, for that matter) fails.

The only thing that solves this problem is a reset of the network interface or a hard reboot. I'm wondering if anyone else has ever run into this issue - and if so, if they have a solution for it.

Any information would be greatly appreciated! Thank you everyone.

Comment: Wait just a sec... "*I have a private server sitting on my residential public/remote IP Address.*" Do you mean to say that you have this machine sitting on your network directly connected to the modem *facing* the Internet *without* being behind a firewall?    Can you please clarify?

Comment: Also, the "server" is it macOS or Windows (or something else).  And the client...is that macOS or Windows as well.  And when you say you have to either reboot or restart the network service, is that on the sever or on the client?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have clarified. The server is in fact behind a firewall, and I have no issues connecting to it from any other machines. The server is an ubuntu server box, and the client machine in question is macOS

Comment: And the rebooting?  Is that macOS or Ubuntu?

Comment: Rebooting on the client machine, macOS, will cause the problem to go away. It doesn't seem to be a problem with my server or firewall as I can connect on any other machine, just not my MBP.

Comment: Seems to me like a DNS problem. Do you use a local DNS server, the router DNS server or a remote one? Also, when you experience the problem, check what `nslookup <servername>` says. Also check what it says when you ask your DNS servrver directly using `nslookup <servername> <ip-of-dns-server>`. Please add the results to your question.

Comment: Can you reach the server?  Try pinging it.

Comment: Pinging the server doesn't work either. It's like a total network block trying to reach this IP address. I will try and recreate the problem and run nslookup.

Comment: Did you try pinging the IP address?

Comment: Malfunctioning VPN has been causing similar issues on my Mac. The VPN client changed the routing table when connecting, but did not restore it properly when disconnecting.